# How to resolve "The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again."?

Tags: magento2.3, orders, magento2.3.0, stores, order-grid

I don't know why it is not accessing my orders page in backend admin, When I navigating to Admin dashboard -> Sales -> Orders. I am having this issue "**The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.**" I cannot able to see my orders list, I can able to see an order from customers view but not in orders.

In logs, I have below text

```
    main.CRITICAL: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. [] []
[2019-11-18 23:27:17] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'global.notices', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-11-18 23:27:17] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-11-18 23:27:17] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' an element cannot be added as a child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-11-18 23:27:17] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-11-18 23:27:17] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'menu' element cannot be added as a child to
```

Please help me to fix this issue. I have a project deadline. below is the attachment. Please suggest the best solution for this, I tried a few solutions from StackOverflow but no luck. Thank you.

[image]
Issue at Sales-> Orders Grid

[image]
My stores table
Please let me know how to fix it

Comment: Have you deleted any store from backend?

Comment: No, I haven't deleted any store. I have multiple stores but not deleted any, default having this problem, All other stores working properly.

Comment: I have updated the query, can you look into it @DhadukMitesh Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got resolved this issue which is causing by 3rd party Mailchimp module, I uninstalled it and the cache flushed then I got resolved the issue.

- Might be Mailchimp using any store access as default or some other, so It was conflicted.
- I disabled and installed another third-party module which is working currently as expected.

Thank you @DhadukMitesh to looking into the issue finally I fixed myself.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Mailchimp module do you have? this is an old issue, and you can fix it updating them module to the current version.
Take a look at https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/releases to know what version you must install